# Getting Text fonts from a pdf file using iText

Tags: itext

I have been trying to extract the attributes(font, font size, color etc.) of each word in a pdf document using iText library. I could extract the text from every page but not the attributes. Also i didn't find anything that could provide the same as such. Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check that all used fonts are embedded in PDF with Java iText?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646130/how-to-check-that-all-used-fonts-are-embedded-in-pdf-with-java-itext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Java person so I can't give you working code but hopefully I can get you 95% of the way there.

First you'll need to create a class that implements the interface [`com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextExtractionStrategy`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/TextExtractionStrategy.html)

Then you can pass an instance of this class as the third parameter to:

[`PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(PdfReader reader, int pageNumber, TextExtractionStrategy strategy)`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/PdfTextExtractor.html#getTextFromPage%28com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader,%20int,%20com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextExtractionStrategy%29)

One of the methods of that interface is [`renderText`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/RenderListener.html#renderText%28com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextRenderInfo%29) which gets called for every text block that gets processed. When it gets called a [`TextRenderInfo`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/TextRenderInfo.html) gets passed in which has a method called [`getFont`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/TextRenderInfo.html#getFont%28%29) which should give you what you're looking for. Store the contents of that in a buffer of some sort and after `getTextFromPage` is called you can inspect that buffer to see each font. If you want to see an example of implementing that interface lookup the code for [`SimpleTextExtractionStrategy`](http://itext.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itext/trunk/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/SimpleTextExtractionStrategy.java?revision=5033&view=markup) online. Otherwise [here's a C# version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882098/how-can-i-get-text-formatting-with-itextsharp) that pretty much does what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a ton for the reply. I didn't know the concept of callback functions in Java (like 'renderText' here). I could get the font names applying getFullFontName() on the object from getFont() method mentioned in the documentation of "Document Font".    :-)