# Itext: How to retrieve list of not embedded fonts of a pdf

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext

I would like to check for a PDF if all fonts are embedded or not. I followed the coding as mentionned in [How to check that all used fonts are embedded in PDF with Java iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646130/how-to-check-that-all-used-fonts-are-embedded-in-pdf-with-java-itext) but I still not able to get a proper list of fonts used.

See my example pdf: https://www.dropbox.com/s/anvm49vh87d8yqs/000024944.pdf?dl=0, the coding returs no fonts at all but the document properties in acrobat mention Helvetica + Verdana (Embedded Subset) + Verdana-Bold (Embedded Subset). For other pdf's I do get Verdana Embedded subset, only for these kind of pdf's I fail to get the font list.

As we have to deal with a huge amount of pdf's from internal as external sources we need to be able to embed fonts in order to print them. As it is almost impossible to embed all fonts we just want to embed common fonts, for exotic fonts we would ignore the printrequest.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: correct link to the pdf https://www.dropbox.com/s/anvm49vh87d8yqs/000024944.pdf?dl=0

Comment: I checked your file with callas pdfToolbox (caution, I'm affiliated with this tool) and it states that Verdana and Verdana bold are embedded (and subsetted) but Helvetica is NOT embedded; which is the same as Adobe Acrobat reports.

Comment: And a somewhat "beside topic" comment - you do realize that embedding even standard fonts is a dangerous thing to do right? There is no guarantee that your copy of the font is the same as the one used by the original PDF file creator and you might end up with different widths, or encoding problems while embedding fonts.

Comment: If I copy the text to a word document I dont find any reference to Helvetica font, so I guess it is not used at all??
I managed to get the fonts in a different way using Itext (see reply below). It is also not returning Helvetica at all.

Comment: Helvetica is defined as `/F2`, and is only used in empty text strings: `() Tj      % show text string` (lots of them). So if it is "used" or not depends on your definition of "used".

Answer (score 2):

Got it working after all by referring to BASEFONT instead of FONT:

```
/**
 * Creates a Set containing information about the fonts in the src PDF file.
 * @param src the path to a PDF file
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void listFonts(PdfReader reader,  Set<String> set) throws IOException {

    try {

        int n = reader.getXrefSize();
        PdfObject object;
        PdfDictionary font;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            object = reader.getPdfObject(i);
            if (object == null || !object.isDictionary()) {
                 continue;
            }

            font = (PdfDictionary)object;

            if (font.get(PdfName.BASEFONT) != null) {
                System.out.println("fontname " + font.getAsName(PdfName.BASEFONT).toString());
                processFont(font,set);

            }

        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error " + e.getMessage());
    }


}

/**
 * Finds out if the font is an embedded subset font
 * @param font name
 * @return true if the name denotes an embedded subset font
 */
private boolean isEmbeddedSubset(String name) {
    //name = String.format("%s subset (%s)", name.substring(8), name.substring(1, 7));
    return name != null && name.length() > 8 && name.charAt(7) == '+';
}

private void processFont(PdfDictionary font, Set<String> set) {

        **String name = font.getAsName(PdfName.BASEFONT).toString();**

        if(isEmbeddedSubset(name)) {
            return;
        }

        PdfDictionary desc = font.getAsDict(PdfName.FONTDESCRIPTOR);

        //nofontdescriptor
        if (desc == null) {
            System.out.println("desc null " );
            PdfArray descendant = font.getAsArray(PdfName.DESCENDANTFONTS);

            if (descendant == null) {
                System.out.println("descendant null " );
                set.add(name.substring(1));             
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("descendant not null " );
                for (int i = 0; i < descendant.size(); i++) {
                    PdfDictionary dic = descendant.getAsDict(i);
                    processFont(dic, set);                    
                  }             
            }            
        }
        /**
         * (Type 1) embedded
         */
        else if (desc.get(PdfName.FONTFILE) != null) {
            System.out.println("(TrueType) embedded ");
        }

        /**
         * (TrueType) embedded 
         */
        else if (desc.get(PdfName.FONTFILE2) != null) {
            System.out.println("(FONTFILE2) embedded ");
        }

        /**
         * " (" + font.getAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE).toString().substring(1) + ") embedded" 
         */     
        else if (desc.get(PdfName.FONTFILE3) != null) {
            System.out.println("(FONTFILE3) ");
        }

        else {
            set.add(name.substring(1));         
        }


}
```

This gives me the same results as list of fonts in acrobat reader>properties

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get some results by combining coding from [How to check that all used fonts are embedded in PDF with Java iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646130/how-to-check-that-all-used-fonts-are-embedded-in-pdf-with-java-itext) and http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=288.
Initially it was not working as font.getAsName(PdfName.BASEFONT).toString(); is not working in my case but I did a small change and get some results.

Below is my coding:

```
/**
 * Creates a Set containing information about the fonts in the src PDF file.
 * @param src the path to a PDF file
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void listFonts(PdfReader reader,  Set<String> set) throws IOException {

    int n = reader.getXrefSize();
    PdfObject object;
    PdfDictionary font;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         object = reader.getPdfObject(i);
         if (object == null || !object.isDictionary()) {
             continue;
         }

         font = (PdfDictionary)object;

         if (font.get(PdfName.FONTNAME) != null) {

            System.out.println("fontname " + font.get(PdfName.FONTNAME));
            processFont(font,set);

         }
    }
}

/**
 * Finds out if the font is an embedded subset font
 * @param font name
 * @return true if the name denotes an embedded subset font
 */
private boolean isEmbeddedSubset(String name) {
    //name = String.format("%s subset (%s)", name.substring(8), name.substring(1, 7));
    return name != null && name.length() > 8 && name.charAt(7) == '+';
}

private void processFont(PdfDictionary font, Set<String> set) {

    String name = font.get(PdfName.FONTNAME).toString();

    if(isEmbeddedSubset(name)) {
        return;
    }

    PdfDictionary desc = font.getAsDict(PdfName.FONTDESCRIPTOR);

    //nofontdescriptor
    if (desc == null) {
        System.out.println("desc null " );
        PdfArray descendant = font.getAsArray(PdfName.DESCENDANTFONTS);

        if (descendant == null) {
            System.out.println("descendant null " );
            set.add(name.substring(1));             
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("descendant not null " );
            for (int i = 0; i < descendant.size(); i++) {
                PdfDictionary dic = descendant.getAsDict(i);
                processFont(dic, set);                    
            }             
        }            
     }
     /**
      * (Type 1) embedded
     */
     else if (desc.get(PdfName.FONTFILE) != null) {
         System.out.println("(TrueType) embedded ");
     }

     /**
      * (TrueType) embedded 
     */
     else if (desc.get(PdfName.FONTFILE2) != null) {
         System.out.println("(FONTFILE2) embedded ");
     }

     /**
     * " (" + font.getAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE).toString().substring(1) + ") embedded" 
     */     
     else if (desc.get(PdfName.FONTFILE3) != null) {
         System.out.println("(FONTFILE3) ");
     }

     else {
         set.add(name.substring(1));         
     }
 }
```

}

So instead of using String name = font.getAsName(PdfName.BASEFONT).toString(); I changed it to String name = font.get(PdfName.FONTNAME).toString();

This definitely get some better results as it gives me different fonts. However I do not get results for fontdescriptor and descendantfonts. Or they are simply not available in my pdf's or because I changed the coding I will never end up there.
Can I assume if a subset is found that the font is embedded, if no subset availbale in the fontname can I assume the font is not embedded?

Comment: This is not an answer, right? You can use the **Edit** button to change your initial post. I am not sure if your *new* questions at the bottom follow logically from what you are asking above, or should better be posted as entirely new questions.

Comment: This was partially an answer as I got some better results. However still had some doubts mainly because I dont completely understand the use of subsets and fonttypes.