# PDF Validation task in ASP.Net web Application while uploading

Tags: java, .net, pdf, itext, aspose

I've been provided with PDF Validation task in my ASP.Net web Application. I need to do Preflight check for the following points.

- Check for presence or barcode or text in a defined area.
- Check for embedded font issues.
- Check for image transparent issue.
- Check version.

I have checked for the options available like Itextsharp etc but they are not fulfilling my requirement. Please help.

Comment: Each of your issues are very vague. For instance "embedded font issues" could mean fonts that your system doesn't support, missing glyphs, missing embedded fonts, too many embedded fonts, not enough embedded fonts, fonts name "Helvetica" that are embedded but shouldn't be. Same with each of your other bullet points. If you have something specific that you want to know we might be able to help you.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for responding on my query. I'm briefing you with the scenario. User is uploading a PDF, we need to check missing embedded fonts, If so we need we need to correct it.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4646130/231316) for a start on listing all fonts in a PDF and determining if they are embedded or not. The code is Java but that's easily translatable to C#.

Answer (score 0):

My name is Tilal Ahmad and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.

You may try [Aspose.Pdf for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/.net/pdf-component.aspx) to accomplish your requirements:

**- Check for presence or barcode or text in a defined area.**

For checking text in a defined PDF page region, please check following documetnation link of Aspose.Pdf for .NET and analyze the extracted text string(extractedText).

[Extract Text from an particular page region](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Extract+Text+from+an+particular+page+region)

To check presence of barcode in a defined PDF page area. Initially You should [convert a specific page region to image](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfjava/Convert+a+particular+page+region+to+Image+%28DOM%29) and then use Aspose.Barcode [to detect barcode](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/barcodenet/Read+Barcode+from+Specific+Region+of+Image) from that image.

**- Check for embedded font issues.**

If you meant to embed un-embedded fonts into PDF document by "checking missing embedded fonts...to correct it"  then you may try this documentation link of Aspose.Pdf for .NET for the purpose.

[Embedding fonts in an existing PDF document](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Embedding+Fonts+in+an+existing+PDF+file)

**- Check version.**

You may load your PDF document to Aspose.Pdf.Document() object and get the PDF version as following.

```
Aspose.Pdf.Document doc = new Aspose.Pdf.Document("input.pdf");
Console.WriteLine("PDF version: {0}",doc.Version);
```

**- Check for image transparent issue.**

For image transparency issue we need some investigation, if possible you can post your sample document and details in [Aspose.PDF forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.pdf-product-family/20/showforum.aspx). We will look into it and guide you.

Furthermore, if you want to validate some PDFA standard then you may load PDF document to Aspose.Pdf.Document() object and use Validate method.

[Validate PDF document for PDFA standard](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Validate+PDF+Document+for+PDF+A+Standard+%28A+1A+and+A+1B%29)

Comment: Hi @Tilal Ahmad , Thanks for helping me and giving reference for ASPOSE. Now I'm using the same and it has resolved all my issues.

Comment: Hi @Tilal Ahmad, Could you please help me for the Pdf Format conversion to PDF_X_1A. Below is my code. After the document conversion if we check the document again yje if condition fails. Please help. 
if (!pdfDocument.Validate("validation-result-X1A.xml",PdfFormat.PDF_X_1A))

Comment: @Ishan Adarsh, We need to investigate your document. Please post a query along with input/output documents in [Aspose.PDF forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.pdf-product-family/20/showforum.aspx). We will look into it and will guide you accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Tilal Ahmad, as per your comment I have raise the query in ASPOSE Community... Please help as I am middle of the code development and will be purchasing a licence soon. [ASPOSE REQUEST LINK](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/706382/how-to-convert-pdf-to-pdf-x-1a-format-with-aspose.pdf/showthread.aspx#)

Comment: @Ishan, Thanks we will investigate and update you in the Aspose.Pdf forum.

Comment: Hi @TilalAhmad I'm eagerly waiting for the response !!! Please help ASAP. If you need the issue replication at your end then I can help for you out.

Comment: @Ishan, We had replicated the issue and logged a ticket in our issue tracking system for rectification. We will keep you updated about the issue resolution progress in the [Aspose Forum thread](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/706382/how-to-convert-pdf-to-pdf-x-1a-format-with-aspose.pdf.aspx).